# How to completely delete items when using @ObservedResults in Realm and SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, realm

I'm trying the new `Realm 10` wrappers by using the example given in the `Realm` documentation [Integration Guides -> SwiftUI & Combine](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/integrations/swiftui/) and I like how simple it is to add and delete records when using the `@ObservedResults` and the `@ObservedRealmObject`. The one thing I don't quite understand is why when deleting items from the `Group` object it only removes the items from the `Group` but leaves the actual items in the `Item` Realm object undeleted. See the Realm Browser image below.

Here is what the Realm Browser shows after adding and deleting four (4) items through the app UI, as you can see the four (4) items were deleted from the `Group` but left all four (4) items in the `Item` object.

[image]

Can someone please explain why the items don't get deleted from the `Item` object only from the `Group` object when calling `.onDelete(perform: $group.items.remove)`? How can I delete them?

I tried deleting them like this...

#### ItemsView.swift

```
.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)


func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet){
    let realm = try? Realm()
    
    try! realm?.write {
        // 1. delete items
        for item in list.items{
            realm?.delete(item)
        }
        // 2. delete the list
        realm?.delete(list)
    }
}
```

but I got the following error:

> Thread 1: "Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to."

Again, the whole code can be found in the [Integration Guides](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/integrations/swiftui/) - Without Sync.

##### EDIT: Added code for, LocalOnlyContentView, ItemsView, Group and Item models.

### Item.swift

```
    import Foundation
    import RealmSwift

    /// Random adjectives for more interesting demo item names
    let randomAdjectives = [
        "fluffy", "classy", "bumpy", "bizarre", "wiggly", "quick", "sudden",
        "acoustic", "smiling", "dispensable", "foreign", "shaky", "purple", "keen",
        "aberrant", "disastrous", "vague", "squealing", "ad hoc", "sweet"
    ]
    /// Random noun for more interesting demo item names
    let randomNouns = [
        "floor", "monitor", "hair tie", "puddle", "hair brush", "bread",
        "cinder block", "glass", "ring", "twister", "coasters", "fridge",
        "toe ring", "bracelet", "cabinet", "nail file", "plate", "lace",
        "cork", "mouse pad"
    ]

    final class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
        @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
        @Persisted var name = "\(randomAdjectives.randomElement()!) \(randomNouns.randomElement()!)"
        @Persisted var isFavorite = false
        @Persisted(originProperty: "items") var group: LinkingObjects<Group>
    }
```

### Group.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift


final class Group: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var items = RealmSwift.List<Item>()
}
```

### ItemsView.swift

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var group: Group

    var leadingBarButton: AnyView?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // The list shows the items in the realm.
                List {
                    ForEach(group.items) { item in
                        ItemRow(item: item)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: $group.items.remove)
                    .onMove(perform: $group.items.move)
                }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    .navigationBarTitle("Items", displayMode: .large)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarItems(
                        leading: self.leadingBarButton,
                        trailing: EditButton())
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        $group.items.append(Item())
                    }) { Image(systemName: "plus") }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### LocalOnlyContentView.swift

```
struct LocalOnlyContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Group.self) var groups
    
    var body: some View {
        if let group = groups.first {
            AnyView(ItemsView(group: group))
        } else {
            AnyView(ProgressView().onAppear {
                $groups.append(Group())
            })
        }
    }
}
```

### SceneDelegate.swift

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    let contentView = LocalOnlyContentView()
    
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're model may be off - the Item object should have a group property if you are trying to match the guide. Can you include your group and item model please?

Comment: See updated code. I also added code for the SceneDelegate, LocalOnlyContentView and ItemsView. Please note that I copied and pasted the code directly from my project. Thanks Jay!

Comment: It appears what's in the RealmStudio screenshot doesn't match those models. The Item class has an isFavorite property and that's not in the Item model in the screenshot.

Comment: No, it's there, it's not shown on the screenshot because I have the Group selected not the Item, please note that I purposely have the Group selected to be able to show the mismatch of items in both objects. Have you by any chance tried the code in the example? If yes, do the items get deleted from both objects? Can you please look at the SceneDelegate, that part I wasn't sure because the example shows an older version of SwiftUI. Thanks.

Comment: Oops - you are correct, I overlooked it. So in that shot, you have a Group with a List property of items that contains no items. e.g. A List is a "pointer" to items so if you delete an item from a List, it still exists in Realm, just not in the List. If you delete the actual item, it will also remove it from the List.  So this `group.items.remove` would remove it from the List, not from Realm. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, if you look at both, I deleted all four (4) items calling `$group.items.remove` but they are still shown in the `Item` Realm object. What I want is to delete the items from both, the `Group`/List and the `Item` object itself. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Right, as I mentioned, deleting items from a List, only removes them from the List, it does not delete the actual Item. If you want to delete the actual item, you need to remove the *item* from Realm, not from the List.

Comment: Well that's the part I'm not sure how to do, if you look at my original post/code I tried calling a method on the `.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)` but I got an error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that what's being shown in that tutorial is how to remove an item from a group's List - not how to totally delete the item.

Going very high level with this answer - objects in a List are not the actual objects - they are a "pointer" to the actual item stored on disk.

Suppose you have three items

```
Item 0 
Item 1
Item 2
```

and a Group with List of items

```
MyGroup
   List of items
        Item 0
        Item 1
        Item 2
```

What's actually going on is the List "points" to the items on disk

```
My Group
   List of items
      pointer to Item 0
      pointer to Item 1
      pointer to Item 2
```

So when this is called `$group.items.remove` it's removing the pointer to the item from the list, not the item itself.

The solution (well, one of the solutions) is to remove the actual item

```
let myItemToRemove = List of items[0] //get the item at index 0

realm.remove(myItemToRemove) // removes the item itself from realm, along 
                             //    with the pointer stored in the list
```

The code to actually delete an item is this

```
try? realm.write {
   realm.delete(objectToDelete)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good explanation about how lists work, that helps.  As far as deleting the Realm objects, I already tried doing that by iterating through all items in the list and I got an error. See my first piece code from my original post. Thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre Yep - I got that. If you note in the guide this `self.realm = realm` which is what the objects where written on initially. At some later point this is in your code `let realm = try? Realm()` which is different. Try using the same realm var that the data was written on.

Comment: I'm using the example without Sync which doesn't have `self.realm = realm`. I will dig into it a little bit more and see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre I was kind using that as an example. The issue is the observed objects Realm and the realm in the delete statement are different. You should be able to get the correct realm from group as in `let realm = group.realm` and then use that realm to delete the groups objects. I don't have the exact code in front of me but that's the idea.

Comment: Got it, I’ll let you know how that goes. Thanks